# Outbound SIP calling with a TwiML Bin: Voice Configuration Request URL

Tags: twilio

Twilio documentation says to set the outbound URL into the "Voice configuration Request URL" but I cannot find this field. Does everyone clueless about this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Basically repeating Alan's answer and comment with a bit more newbie angle, but I cannot comment yet as I don't have the required reputation)

The "A Call Comes In" action for your SIP Domain is, as Alan explains in his comment, for the calls originating from the endpoint or UA. Hence, the simple example TwiML routing the call to a e164 works here.

Calls originating in the PSTN are handled by the TwiML (or other action) set to handle calls coming in to your number, ie. in Programmable Voice -> Numbers -> Manage Numbers -> # -> A Call Comes In.

Comment: Man alive. At first I thought you must be mistaken because that seems like such a terrible design, from my newbie perspective, but you're absolutely right. To handle outgoing calls one must set "A Call Comes In" on the SIP domain, not to be confused with "A Call Comes In" for the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Choose, "A Call Comes In" and set the drop down to Webhook, then paste the URL into that edit box, click Save.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alan, it looks like what you propose is for inbound calls as I did shown in my previous post. I am trying to figure out about outbound calls. Maybe I am confuse with your answer.

Comment: This field in for inbound from the perspective of the SIP End-point or SIP User Agent sending the request to your unique Twilio SIP Domain. Once it hits your SIP Domain, Twilio requests TwiML from the URL you entered in the "A Call Comes In" field.